# Backup Finder sidebar favorites in file

Tags: finder, backup, sidebar

Is there a way to backup my finder sidebar "Favorites" on the left with all my shortcuts to folders on our network drive?
Is this sidebar stored in a file somewhere that I can backup?

Every once in a while the whole sidebar is messed up, so all network folders are gone or the name is just a `?` instead of the real folder name.

If there are many folders it takes way too long to restore all of that by hand (and also I can't remember all those folders until I need it and notice that it's missing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sidebar will forget those mounted network aliases every time it can't find one.

The 'fix', although a bit clunky, is to mount the remote drives, directly alias them on the desktop, then move the aliases somewhere permanent.
Then they never break.

Comment: I'm not sure what I should do now.
This fixes the problem, thank you. But the original question was to back it up in a file. Because I'm relatively new to stackexchange I don't know if it's correct to resolve this as the correct answer

Comment: You could consider it a "frame challenge", a 'how about if you did it this way instead?'. You can accept whichever you like - whichever helped the most, if you want to think of it that way. [I won't be offended if you choose the other answer;))

Answer (score 1):

You can backup file in

`~/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.FavoriteItems.sfl2`

restore this file need to login out.

I test in 10.14.6 ok

Answer (score 0):

There are two plist files in the Library that have all the finder settings.

The files are located at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist` and `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`

You can open one by copying the path, opening finder, click on `go`, then `go to folder` and paste the path in there. This way you can create and restore a backup of the sidebar.

Comment: The files are there, but if I backup that file, delete something in my sidebar and put the file back it won't restore the sidebar.

Comment: After you restore the file you have to log out and log in again for the changes to take effect. A restart also works.

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to use alternate methods of 'saving' network shares as aliases in the Finder, e.g. on the Desktop (or better, in a sub-folder of the Desktop to keep things tidy!); or in the Dock.